# running base android on S4

Tags: cyanogenmod

I have an s4...tired of the bloat I rooted and flashed CyanogenMod onto device...

Frustrating...nothing on phone works...Facebook YouTube and other apps crash on load...

Unfortunately X has stopped is the error I get

Facebook just closes...no error

The time system tray display doesn't update I have to use clock app to get time at which point the system tray 'sometimes' updates.

My alarms don't work...I can configure them but no sounds...volume is cranked

I am certain something fubared during flashing I had several problems getting it going

I am looking into other distros...but base android appeals to me...however I understand the base won't likely have required drivers hence mods like cyanogen for S4

Restoring the default ROM is an option I think...I believe I backed up before flashing...

Anyway...what are my options here... Suggestions??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your options are:-

1. Re-flash the stock ROM, either from your backup or by finding it on sammobile.com.
2. Flash a working Cyanogenmod. Be sure to use a stable release, not a nightly build. Nightlies are not suitable for day-to-day use and often contain serious bugs. And to use the apps you've mentioned, you'll need to flash the *gapps* package that matches your Android version.
3. Flash some other ROM. [Where can I find stock or custom ROMs for my Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/17152/where-can-i-find-stock-or-custom-roms-for-my-android-device)
4. Ditch your phone and buy one with a minimal ROM, such as a Nexus.